# Get Post object by page

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I tried to get certain amount of Post objects per page (like 10) and I tried that using extension methods

```
  int _start = _page * _listItemsPerPage;
  int _end = (_page + 1) * _listItemsPerPage;

  if (Posts.Count > _end)
       return  (Posts.Skip(_start).Take(_end - _start)) as List<Post>;
  else
       return  (Posts.Skip(_start).Take(Posts.Count - _start)) as List<Post>;
```

But I've done something wrong because It allways returns null .
Aditional info:

- Posts is List< Post > Type, collection of dummie data
- _page - page number
- _listItemsPerPage - how many items are needed to be displayed
- _start - starting index
- _end  - ending index
- I've done prior exception check

Answer (score 1):

The calls to Skip and Take return an `IEnumerable<Post>`, not a `List<Post>`, so converting to a `List<Post>` with `as List<Post>` fails and returns null.

Either add call to `AsList()`, or just return the `IEnumerable<Post>`.